# Creating generic scripts by importing test data

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

My supervisor wants me to import test data in test script. I don't understand what he exactly wants me to do. He said, I was creating scripts for a particular client's website, so next time I would need to replace many values in test script when I'm testing website of other client. I don't know how I can create .csv or excel file to import test data. :( I know nothing about it.
I'm using TestNG, eclipse and webdriver.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest talking to your supervisor, explaining that you don't understand and that you would require an example of what he wants so that you can follow it yourself.

Comment: I agree with @MarkRowlands .  If the supervisor doesn't explain much on that, then since you are using java, what i'd recommend is the same type of concept that the [getting started with selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) project uses.  Each test class has the option of pulling a properties file of the same name.  for example, `Test1.java` can pull `Test1.properties` which contains data that you can use in the test.